# Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qv2ray.list (Component)

Tags: apt, package-management

I tried to run `sudo apt update`, but an error appeared:

```
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qv2ray.list (Component)
The list of sources could not be read.
```

When I check `qv2ray.list` file it shows:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://qv2ray.net/debian-dev/  main
```

What can I do?

Comment: Your message tells you the error is in line 1 of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/qv2ray.list`, as the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty on a new install, someone with `sudo` rights has added that file containing errors.  You need to correct those errors.